# How to center the image in CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I cannot get the image in the center of desktop. The image is alway on the left side. It is LinearLayout I some ScrollView.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/titelbild280x280"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete XML file?

Answer (score 8):

CardView is an extension of FrameLayout. So you should use the same layout values as you would in a FrameLayout.
To center a child view you use:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

So your layout becomes:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/titelbild280x280"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

However, note that the CardView in this example uses wrap_content, so it will firmly wrap the image and there will be nothing left to center. For the gravity to have effect the CardView has to be larger than the ImageView.

Comment: I've made even the image very small and changed to match content in CardView but anyway it doesn't work `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
.....

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/titelbild_100x100" />`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a layout (`ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`) for managing multiple view in card view 
Currently android UI system deeply coupled with `ConstraintLayout` for handling complex layout and making it easily, so following codes maybe help to you

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/titelbild280x280"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Hope it will work for you

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/featureimage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/some_img" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/titelbild280x280"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope its works for you.

Comment: welcome , if its working for you please give me some points and mark as a right answer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that worked for me was using relative layout inside my cardView and then using the android:layout_centerInParent="true".
This works perfectly when the width and height of the of the relative layout are match parent (Parent being the cardView).